# Can you recover an original traffic citation in California after the court retention time frame?

Tags: california, traffic, court-records

the USCIS is asking me for all criminal records or traffic offenses since I arrived in the United States 7 years ago. My only incident so far has been a traffic ticket for not showing evidence of insurance registration in 2017, which was settled with a fee after I pleaded guilty. However I never got my hands on the original citation (I changed addresses a lot during that time), and the Orange County Court seems to only keep records of traffic offenses for 3 years (https://www.occourts.org/directory/civil/general-information/record-requests.html).

Is there a way I can recover the original citation or some certified surrogate of it?

Comment: It might help if you say what specific information/documentation you need for the USCIS.

Comment: Are you filling out an N-400? I don't think your citation fulfills the requirements for reporting it. See Note on the instructions, page 13-14. https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/n-400instr.pdf